# python sqlite3 sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

I tried to check if duplicate link is in the db -> pass, else add link into db

Using this code Makes Error

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Link_Date (link) SELECT (?) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Link_Date WHERE (link) = (?))" ,value)
```

In this case The error is appear like this

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.
```

So I tried to add one more value, And this error appear.

TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

The value is URL Type. And how to escape : character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executemany` wants you to provide multiple bindings as a single list argument, like this:

```py
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Link_Date (link) SELECT (?) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Link_Date WHERE (link) = (?))", [value1, value2])
```

Comment: Thanks For answering to my question. the value must be different? or it can be same value?

Comment: You can provide any values there. The number and order of values in the list should correspond to the number of `?` in the SQL query. 

This is a common approach in SQL called "parameter binding", used to avoid an SQL injection vulnerability by properly escaping the parameters before sending them to the database.